# Simplification of similar commands in Makefiles

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile:

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -g

all: ex1.c 
    cc ex1.c -o ex1
    valgrind ./ex1
    cc ex2.c -o ex2
    valgrind ./ex2
    cc ex3.c -o ex3
    valgrind ./ex3

clean:
    rm -f ex1
    rm -f ex2
    rm -f ex3
```

Is there any way of simplifying this so I do not have to add 3 lines per file (I am expecting ~50 files) and instead I can just insert a number and it will run the commands for that number of files?  All of the files will have the same naming scheme `/^ex\d{1,}\.c/` and are all in the same directory.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not necessarily need loops:

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -g

ALL_EX=ex1 ex2 ex3

all: $(ALL_EX)

ex%: ex%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@.c -o $@
    valgrind ./$@

clean: ; rm -f $(ALL_EX)
```

To add another test, all you need is to add another `exN` to the `ALL_EX` variable.

Or alternatively, splitting the `valgrind` invocation from the compilation:

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -g

ALL_EX=ex1 ex2 ex3
TEST_EX=$(ALL_EX:ex%=test_ex%)

all: $(TEST_EX)
cmp: $(ALL_EX)

ex%: ex%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@.c -o $@
test_ex%: ex%
    valgrind ./$<

clean: ; rm -f $(ALL_EX)
```

That way you would also avoid redundant recompilation of the `ex*.c` files. And most importantly: this way you can parallelize the compilation and the tests with the `make -j`.

Comment: I definitely approve of separating the `valgrind` run into a separate rule, but why not make it a rule for creating a *bona fide* file, such as one containing valgrind's output?  Or if you do not do that, then at least mark the `test_ex%` as `.PHONY`.

Comment: I'm not making assumption about how OP uses the make or valgrind. I have focused only on the question asked: automating the compilation and testing of many files.

Comment: That's fine, but a target whose recipe does not generate the file designated by the target name should be declared `.PHONY`.  This has nothing to do with how the OP intends to use the `make` or `valgrind`, and everything to do with defining the correct semantics to `make`.  In particular, it's about what to do in the event that the build directory happens to contain a file with the same name as the target.

Comment: Your rules are missing prerequisites.

Comment: Unless the OP explicitly asks for it, I'm not going to burden the answer with the banal nitpicks.

Comment: The files won't be updated. This is the main point of make. Op will be confused.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, btw, you can't add `test_ex*` targets to `.PHONY` since phony targets never match rules with `%`.

Comment: @Dummy00001 what would you recommend?  I am working my way through Lean C The Hard Way and am saving each exercise in an appropriately named file.  What I want this to be able to do is remove all output files, build the files and test them with valgrind.

Comment: I hate to mention it, but the compile line should mention CFLAGS:  as in      cc $(CFLAGS) $@.c -o $@

Comment: @ComputerBackup, if you are still learning, then this would suffice. My personal way of learning is different: first study the underlaying concepts, then learn by doing. Small games are probably the most common starting point for many: learn coding while having some fun. There are plenty of books for the 2D game programming. You can pick many used ones very cheaply.